# How to display query result in a Hash in view Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

My controller has the following query :

```
# reports_between_two_dates is already defined
@data_count_by_city = reports_between_two_dates
                        .joins('JOIN "places" ON "places"."id"="reported_regs"."reported_place_id" JOIN "cities" ON "places"."city_id" = "cities"."id" ')
                        .where('"reported_regs"."reported_place_id" IN (SELECT "places"."id" FROM "places") AND "places"."city_id" IN (SELECT "cities"."id" FROM "cities")')
                        .group('"display_name"')
                        .select('COUNT(*) AS count, "display_name" AS cities')
                        .order('count DESC')
                        .limit(3)
```

I also have this in the controller :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { 
    render json: { 
    html: render_to_string(
      partial: 'data_stats', 
      locals: { 
        data_count_by_city: @data_count_by_city
    }) } }
  format.html
end
```

The query's result in psql is as follows :

```
 count |    cities     
-------+---------------
   409 | NYC
   244 | SF
   156 | LA
```

My end goal is to display the above result as a hash, having as keys the cities, and the count as values..

In the view I've tried doing :

```
<td><%= Hash[@data_count_by_city.map{ |r| [r.cities,r.count] }] %></td>
```

But all I get is an empty hash..
What am I missing?

Comment: What's the query result in Ruby: `@data_count_by_city.inspect`?

Comment: so, you want to render a hash in erb?

Comment: @Leito the result is : #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: @marmeladze I want to render the result of that query in the view

Comment: There are no results, and that's why you get an empty  hash. So let's go back to the query and forget about the controller and view. What's the query   in SQL? What's the query you see in the logs of your Rails Server?

Comment: You should not need a custom join string if your associations are properly defined. Can you include the models?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Leito ! Could you please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved? Actually the query is correct. When I ran it on PSQL I was testing in the prod database, but the database I'm working on with my Rails project is not fairly populated as the prod db. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction :)!

Comment: Thanks @max for your answer! I solved the problem, it was just a silly mistake, please refer to my previous comment

Comment: What is that WHERE clause supposed to do? It seems totally redundant since you're just selecting everything off the joined table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the relation was returning no results (empty relation: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`). OP find out he was running the query on Production and the code on a different environment.

Other than that, the code seems to work as expected, as long as `@data_count_by_city` stores an array-like structure with both `cities` and `count`. On that note, I think

`.group('display_name').count` shouldn't need the `.select('COUNT(*) AS count, "display_name" AS cities')`

Comment: Thanks a lot Leito for the heads up :) Btw if I select certain dates I get an empty hash I assume it's because of the Inner Join, I tried doing the Outer Join but I still get no results. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, but same advice goes: compare the queries in your server logs to the ones in `psql`. Then slowly deconstruct the query to see what causes it to be empty.